# Ruby on Rails: Using default value, when the variable is null or empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code-snippet in html erb.

For some objects the cover_image_url is empty, how do i modify this code block to use a default value ,when that property is null or empty?

```
<%@books.each do |book|%>
        $('#bookContainer').append('<div class="conn"><p><img class="floatright" src="<%= h book.cover_image_url%>"><h3><%= h book.title%></h3><h3><%= h book.author%></h3></p></div>');
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could define a `cover_image_url` method on your book model that will return a default value if there is nothing set in the database (I am assuming that cover_image_url is a column in the book table). Something like this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  def cover_image_url
    read_attribute(:cover_image_url).presence || "/my_default_link"
  end
end
```

This will return `"/my_default_link"` if the attribute is not set, or the value of the attribute if it is set. See section 5.3 on The Rails 3 Way for more info on this stuff. Defining a default value for a model in the model layer may be a little cleaner than doing it in the view layer.

Comment: If you want to treat blanks as nulls for this purpose, you may want to change it to `read_attribute(:cover_image_url).presence || "/my_default_link"`.  `presence` returns the object if it isn't blank, otherwise returns nil.

Comment: From this [Rubocop Styleguide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rails-style-guide#read-attribute) you can see that the preferred is
`self[:amount]` not `read_attribute(:amount)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a local variable inside the loop :

```
<% url = book.cover_image_url or "/my_default_link" %>
```

This will take a default link if the first value is nil.

To check both null or empty :

```
<% url = ((book.cover_image_url.nil? or (book.cover_image_url and book.cover_image_url.empty?)) ? "/my_default_link" : book.cover_image_url) %>
```

Put the whole thing in a helper to make it cleaner.

Comment: **or** didn't work for me; this was my solution: `url = book.cover_image_url || "/my_default_link"`